# Autospec not failing when call is made with too few args

Tags: python-2.7, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am trying figure out the best way to use autospec in my tests. In the following scenario I use autospec to detect when a call is made with too many args. This scenario works as expected when called with `$ python filename.py`.

```
import unittest
import mock

class FakeDependency(object):
    def set_obj(arg1, arg2):
        self.foo = arg1
        self.bar = arg2


class FakeObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fake_dependency = FakeDependency()

    def set_dependency(self):
        self.fake_dependency.set_obj('foo', 'bar', 'buz')  # Bug


class TestFakeObject(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch.object(FakeDependency, 'set_obj')
    def test_set_dependency_with_assert_called(self, mock_dependency):
        r = FakeObject()
        r.set_dependency()
        mock_dependency.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'bar', 'buz')  # Test passes does not catch bug


    @mock.patch.object(FakeDependency, 'set_obj', autospec=True)
    def test_set_dependency_with_autospec(self, mock_dependency):
        r = FakeObject()
        r.set_dependency()  # Test Fails


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But if I change the test case to detect when too few args are called then it passes and doesn't catch the bug.

```
class FakeDependency(object):
    def set_obj(arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.foo = arg1
        self.bar = arg2
        self.buz = arg3


class FakeObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fake_dependency = FakeDependency()

    def set_dependency(self):
        self.fake_dependency.set_obj('foo', 'bar')  # Bug


class TestFakeObject(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch.object(FakeDependency, 'set_obj')
    def test_set_dependency_with_assert_called(self, mock_dependency):
        r = FakeObject()
        r.set_dependency()
        mock_dependency.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'bar')  # Test passes does not catch bug


    @mock.patch.object(FakeDependency, 'set_obj', autospec=True)
    def test_set_dependency_with_autospec(self, mock_dependency):
        r = FakeObject()
        r.set_dependency()  # Test Also passes
```

So my question is what am doing wrong? According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) autospec should also detech when too few args are passed.

Comment: I just ran it using python filename.py

Comment: @sxn that was my problem, when I changed the call to python -m unittest filename it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're running the tests correctly? I copy+pasted the code from your first snippet into a `main.py` file, installed mock and ran it using `python -m unittest main` and got `TypeError: too many positional arguments`, which is what you'd expect. :)

Answer (score 1):

As sxn pointed out I was calling the test wrong. When I called the test like this it worked as expected.

```
$ python -m unittest filename
```